What is the default font used for code blocks
This might be a very silly question, but I really didn't find the answer using Google.
As far as I know, the font used by LaTeX for body text is Computer Modern. But what is the default font used by LaTeX for code blocks and inline code spans?
This is an inline \texttt{code} span.

\begin{verbatim}
This is
a code
block.
\end{verbatim}


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is an inline \texttt{code} span.

\begin{verbatim}
This is
a code
block.
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}

produces a terminal output and log that ends
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on 

which lists all the fonts used. cmr10.pfb is computer modern roman 10 pt, the main body font and cmtt10 is computer modern monospace 10 pt, the default font used for \texttt and related commands,
